# Can a bash array be used in place of eval set -- "$params"?

Tags: bash, array, options, parameter, getopts

I'm taking a look at the [optparse library](https://github.com/nk412/optparse/blob/master/optparse.bash) for `bash` option parsing, specifically this bit in the generated code:

```
params=""
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
  param="$1"
  shift

  case "$param" in

    --my-long-flag)
      params="$params -m";;
    --another-flag)
      params="$params -a";;
    "-?"|--help)
      usage
      exit 0;;
    *)
      if [[ "$param" == --* ]]; then
        echo -e "Unrecognized long option: $param"
        usage
        exit 1
      fi
      params="$params \"$param\"";;  ##### THIS LINE
  esac
done

eval set -- "$params"  ##### AND THIS LINE

# then a typical while getopts loop
```

Would there be any real reason to use `eval` here?  The input to `eval` *seems* to be properly sanitized.  But wouldn't it work the same to use:

```
params=()
# ...
    --my-long-flag)
      params+=("-m");;
    --another-flag)
      params+=("-a");;
# ...
      params+=("$param");;
# ...
set -- "${params[@]}"
```

That seems cleaner to me.

In fact, wouldn't this allow options to be parsed directly out of the `params` array (without even using `set`) by using `while getopts "ma" option "${params[@]}"; do` instead of `while getopts "ma" option; do`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* to use a `bash` array here (but do so if it feels better).

Here's how to do it for `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg do
    shift

    case "$arg" in
        --my-long-flag)
            set -- "$@" -m ;;
        --another-flag)
            set -- "$@" -a ;;
        "-?"|--help)
            usage
            exit 0 ;;
        --*)
            printf 'Unrecognised long option: %s\n' "$arg" >$2
            usage
            exit 1 ;;
        *)
            set -- "$@" "$arg"
    esac
done
```

This is cleaner than the `bash` array solution (personal opinion) since it doesn't need to introduce another variable.  It's also better than the auto-generated code that you show as it retains each command line argument as a *separate item* in `"$@"`.  This is good, because this allows the user to pass arguments containing whitespace characters as long as they are quoted (which the auto-generated code does not do).

---

Style comments:

- The loop above is supposed to translate long options into short options for a loop over `getopts` later. As such, it breaks from that task by actually *acting* on some options, such as `-?` and `--help`.  IMHO, these should instead be translated to `-h` (or some suitable short option).
- It also does the translation of long options *past the point where options should not be accepted*.  Calling the script as

  ```
  ./script.sh --my-long-flag -- -?
  ```

  *should* not interpret `-?` as an option due to the `--` (meaning "options ends here").  Likewise,

  ```
  ./script.sh filename --my-long-flag
  ```

  *should* not interpret `--my-long-option` as an option, as the parsing of options should stop at the first non-option.

Here's a variant that takes the above into account:

```
#!/bin/sh

parse=YES

for arg do
    shift

    if [ "$parse" = YES ]; then
       case "$arg" in
            --my-long-flag)
                set -- "$@" -m ;;
            --another-flag)
                set -- "$@" -a ;;
            --help)
                set -- "$@" -h ;;
            --)
                parse=NO
                set -- "$@" -- ;;
            --*)
                printf 'Unrecognised long option: %s\n' "$arg" >$2
                usage
                exit 1 ;;
            *)
                parse=NO
                set -- "$@" "$arg"
        esac
     else
        set -- "$@" "$arg"
     fi

done
```

What this does *not* allow is long options with *separate* option arguments, such as `--option hello` (the `hello` would be treated as a non-option and the option parsing would end).  Something like `--option=hello` would be fairly easy to handle with a bit of extra tinkering though.

Comment: I would love an explanation of how iterating over the positional parameters interacts with changing those positional parameters at the same time.

Comment: @Wildcard The standard `for` loop always iterates over a static list, so once it's started, you can do whatever with `$@`.  The loop range/items is not re-evaluated in each iteration.

Comment: @Wildcard In this instance, you _could_ also do `for dummy do arg=$1; shift; ...; done`.  This would just iterate as many times as the original `$@` had elements but the `dummy` variable would not be used.

Answer (score 4):

The question is "*Should* a bash array be used in place of eval set — “$params”?", and the answer is **yes!**.

In your script, the input to eval is clearly *not* properly sanitized. Try

```
    yourscript '`xterm`'
```

and you'll see that an xterm is started even though the backticks are properly quoted by single quotes. (Compare with

```
    echo '`xterm`'
```

which does not start an xterm.)

Fixing the bug while keepting `eval` is very difficult.
Even changing the line

```
    params="$params \"$param\"";;
```

to

```
    params="$params '$param'";;
```

would not help: Now

```
    yourscript '`xterm`'
```

no longer starts an xterm, but

```
    yourscript \'' `xterm` '\'
```

still does.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm working on a remote box over ssh, so I don't have `xterm` available, but I tested it with ``myscript '`touch /tmp/hacked`'`` (and compared it to ``echo '`touch /tmp/hacked`'``).  I didn't even need the double quotes or the spaces, though; is there a different edge case those are hacking around?

Comment: Also, I've never used `bash` arrays before—I wrote the "cleaner" version that uses arrays after a brief once-over of the applicable man page section.  Did I get it right?  Any pitfalls in it that you see?

Comment: Also **NB: This is not my script.**  I linked to the [optparse library](https://github.com/nk412/optparse/blob/master/optparse.bash) in my question; that's the source of this code.  However, the optparse library is sourced from some other code that I have to maintain, so I want to clean up the vulnerabilities.  I've never used `eval` in a script and probably never will.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard yes, you're right, the double quotes or the spaces are unnecessary, since the script tries to protect `$param` with double quotes, and backticks are evaluated even within double quotes. If `$param` were protected with single quote, one would need a more complicated argument.

Comment: @Wildcard The rest looks fine.

Comment: backticks are [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), I'd recommend using `$(...)` instead.

Comment: @AlexejMagura These are *literal* backticks. They are *properly quoted*. They are *not* supposed to be interpreted -- but they *are* interpreted.

Comment: @Uwe Ahh, so they are; sorry to bother you.